# Invoke REST api protected by OAuth from Azure AD B2C custom policy

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

How to invoke a REST API from Azure AD B2C using token(say client credential flow)

Comment: Have you checked some of the similar threads? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39439830/create-a-new-user-in-azure-active-directory-b2c-with-graph-api-using-http-pos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there isn't any built-in support for this, since `AuthenticationType` must be set to one of `None`, `Basic` or `ClientCertificate`.

If your REST API does allow for this, then you can acquire an access token in a previous step and pass it in to your REST API, via the request query or body.

Comment: you mean to say, in 1st step acquire an access token using technical profile and store it in claim. In 2nd step, use that claim via request header in another rest api tehnical profile. Is it correct? @Chris Padgett

Comment: I am trying to do bearer token authentication. Is it possible to do through policy technical profile.